# Data is loading very slow using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have am trying to pull data from HealthKit, the data is being pulled correctly and with enough speed.  I think there might be something wrong with the way I have GCD set up.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadGraphDataForType:(NSString *)type withDuration:(int)graphDuration {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *interval = [NSDateComponents new];

    if (graphDuration == 1) {

        interval.hour = 1;

    } else {

        interval.day = 1;

    }

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfValues = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSDate *anchorDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];

    HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:type];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([@"graph.queue" UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

        dispatch_semaphore_t lock = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:quantityType quantitySamplePredicate:nil options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum anchorDate:anchorDate intervalComponents:interval];

        query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            } else {

                NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];

                NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-graphDuration toDate:endDate options:0];

                [results enumerateStatisticsFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {

                    HKQuantity *quantity = result.sumQuantity;

                    if (quantity != nil) {

                        double value = 0;

                                //Steps Traveled
                                value = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]];



                        int intValue = (int)value;

                        [arrayOfValues addObject:@(intValue)];

                    } else {

                        [arrayOfValues addObject:@0];

                    }

                }];

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(lock);

            }

        };

        [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(lock, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{

        graphData = [PNLineChartData new];
        graphData.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        graphData.itemCount = [arrayOfValues count];
        graphData.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {

            CGFloat yValue = [arrayOfValues[index] floatValue];
            return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];

        };

        graph.chartData = @[graphData];
        [graph strokeChart];

    });

}
```

If I put a break point where the graph gets the item count, it shows 25 (which is correct) and I can see the data inside of the array, but the graph takes a good 5 minutes before it shows up.  I have tried a few different libraries now and they all behave the same so I think it is something in my code that is causing it.

I am not that familiar with GCD so I'm sure it's something with that.

If anyone has any advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping this `[graph strokeChart];` in a dispatch_async back to the main queue.

Otherwise I would suggest profiling the app with instruments.

Use the Time Profiler to check the execution times and see where the most time is spent.

You can then check the thread view to see where the work is being done and where any waiting occurs.

It doesnt look like you need a dispatch group for this work though.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was answering, I just got rid of all of the semaphore and all that junk.  I just dispatched the results to the main queue per Apple's Documentation and all is working well now.  Thanks!
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery_Class/